# copy std::string between 2 different programs

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, copy, inter-process-communicat

I have a std::string which is generated in some program.
I have another program which should use this string.Meanwhile (for debug purposes)these programs are independent - but I still want to get and process this string in other program.
How can I do that?Can I copy the string as a text (for example representing the string bu text visualizer in debugger) and after that in the second program generate the copy of this string using std::string(text).
The text is ~ 200 lines.

Comment: Do the two programs need to be running at the same time?  And how quickly do you need to pass the string from one to the other?  (I.e. does writing it to a file, and reading it from the file work)?

Comment: Another option is perhaps to set an environment variable

Comment: @phonetagger - for now I want to do that manually.put breakpoint in 1st prog. and somehow copy the string

Comment: Your looking for intercession communication. Save the string to a file and have the other program read that file. This is a simplest method to use.

Comment: How about a socket? That seems like a clean solution. Assuming you use windows [here is a start guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545(VS.85).aspx).